# Ошибка с адаптером или контекстом не пойму

Tags: java, android

Что начит и как убрать ее?

android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Comment: Ошибка при работе с курсором.

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 0):

ошибка значит, что ваш курсор не установлен ни на какую позицию. используйте что то вроде `cursor.moveToFirst()`, чтобы указать, откуда нужно читать данные (в этом случае с первой позиции)